# React Buttons not working, only using fallback styles

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to React, but following multiple guides I have an issue with buttons not selecting the correct style based on "checkButtonStyle", only rendering with the fallback options.

My code is:
(Button.jsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';

const STYLES = ['btn--primary', 'btn--light', 'btn--dark', 'btn--outline', 'btn--outline--light', 'btn--outline--dark'];
const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];

export const Button = ({children, type, onClick, buttonStyle, buttonSize}) => {

    const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle) ? buttonStyle : STYLES[0];

    const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

    return (
        <button className={'btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}'} onClick={onClick} type={type}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
};
```

(Button.css)

```
:root {
    --primary: #EF1B71;
    --light: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 500ms ease;
}

.btn--primary {
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: var(--light);
    border: 1px solid var(--primary);
}

.btn--medium {
    padding: 8px 20px;
}
```

(HeroSection)

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Button } from './Button';
import './HeroSection.css';

function HeroSection() {
    return (
        <div className='hero-container'>
            <video src='/videos/home-hero-video-2.mp4' autoPlay loop muted />
            <div className="hero-btns">
                <Button type='button' buttonStyle='btn--primary' buttonSize="btn--medium">Enquire</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of, with no errors showing in console for the button, however the only result I am getting is the .btn style within Button.css and not the btn--primary or btn--medium styles.

Thank you

Comment: In your hero section component, you are not passing onClick prop.

Comment: It looks like you are using single quotes rather than backticks in your template literal so ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize} won't resolve to their values.

Comment: @RyanO'D Thank you so much, didn't realise that was something different... Problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
className={
      checkButtonSizes + " " + checkButtonStyle + " btn"}
```

You have to pass the variables in the format mentioned above to make it work. It works for me. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, it's possible to use variables in strings with a [JavaScript template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

However, this requires the use of backticks (`) rather than single (') or double (") quotes.

This line uses single quotes rather than backticks. Thus, `${checkButtonStyle}` and `${checkButtonSize}` will be rendered as strings and not their assigned values.

```
<button className={'btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}'} onClick={onClick} type={type}>
```